# How Can I power my LG Monitor?

Tags: display, cable

I bought an used [LG 20M35](http://www.lg.com/ae/monitors/lg-20M35A) but I got scammed and got no power cable. Can I find other cable by myself (non-LG) and plug it safely to my monitor? If so, what cable do I need? Keep in mind that I cannot find an official one online.

Thanks!

Comment: Next to where the power lead plugs in to the monitor, it should tell you what voltage and current it needs, and if it needs a centre-positive or centre-negative connector. If you can't decipher what it says, please take a photo that shows the information in focus and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page 25 of the users manual has part numbers for the ac adapter:

```
AC-DC Adapter
Type ADS-40SG-19-3 19025G, manufactured by SHENZHEN HONOR ELECTRONIC
or Type ADS-40FSG-19 19025GPG-1, manufactured by SHENZHEN HONOR ELECTRONIC
or Type ADS-40FSG-19 19025GPBR-1, manufactured by SHENZHEN HONOR ELECTRONIC
or Type ADS-40FSG-19 19025GPI-1, manufactured by SHENZHEN HONOR ELECTRONIC
or Type ADS-40FSG-19 19025GPCU-1, manufactured by SHENZHEN HONOR ELECTRONIC
or Type ADS-40FSG-19 19025GPB-2, manufactured by SHENZHEN HONOR ELECTRONIC
or Type LCAP21, manufactured by LIEN CHANG ELECTRONIC ENTERPRISE
or Type LCAP26-A, manufactured by LIEN CHANG ELECTRONIC ENTERPRISE
or Type LCAP26-E, manufactured by LIEN CHANG ELECTRONIC ENTERPRISE
or Type LCAP26-I, manufactured by LIEN CHANG ELECTRONIC ENTERPRISE
or Type LCAP26-B, manufactured by LIEN CHANG ELECTRONIC ENTERPRISE
or Type PSAB-L203A, manufactured by LG Innotek Co.,Ltd
or Type PSAB-L202B, manufactured by LG Innotek Co.,Ltd
or Type PSAB-L202C, manufactured by LG Innotek Co.,Ltd
or Type PSAB-L202D, manufactured by LG Innotek Co.,Ltd
OUTPUT: 19 V 1.3 A
Type ADS-18SG-19-3 19016G, manufactured by SHENZHEN HONOR ELECTRONIC
or Type ADS-18FSG-19 19016GPG, manufactured by SHENZHEN HONOR ELECTRONIC
or Type ADS-18FSG-19 19016GPI, manufactured by SHENZHEN HONOR ELECTRONIC
or Type ADS-18FSG-19 19016GPCU, manufactured by SHENZHEN HONOR ELECTRONIC
or Type ADS-18FSG-19 19016GPB, manufactured by SHENZHEN HONOR ELECTRONIC
or Type LCAP42, manufactured by LIEN CHANG ELECTRONIC ENTERPRISE
or Type LCAP36-A, manufactured by LIEN CHANG ELECTRONIC ENTERPRISE
or Type LCAP36-E, manufactured by LIEN CHANG ELECTRONIC ENTERPRISE
or Type LCAP36-I, manufactured by LIEN CHANG ELECTRONIC ENTERPRISE
or Type LCAP36-U, manufactured by LIEN CHANG ELECTRONIC ENTERPRISE
```